# Using input field to get amount from users

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add an input field which automatically converts a character into $ symbol and when a number is entered the amount is returned. But, i want to set a minimum value to $5

My input field already converts a character in $ and a number value in the amount. I just want to add a minimum value of $5

```js
// Jquery Dependency

$("input[data-type='currency']").on({
  keyup: function() {
    formatCurrency($(this));
  },
  blur: function() {
    formatCurrency($(this), "blur");
  }
});


function formatNumber(n) {
  // format number 1000000 to 1,234,567
  return n.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
}


function formatCurrency(input, blur) {
  // appends $ to value, validates decimal side
  // and puts cursor back in right position.

  // get input value
  var input_val = input.val();

  // don't validate empty input
  if (input_val === "") {
    return;
  }

  // original length
  var original_len = input_val.length;

  // initial caret position 
  var caret_pos = input.prop("selectionStart");

  // check for decimal
  if (input_val.indexOf(".") >= 0) {

    // get position of first decimal
    // this prevents multiple decimals from
    // being entered
    var decimal_pos = input_val.indexOf(".");

    // split number by decimal point
    var left_side = input_val.substring(0, decimal_pos);
    var right_side = input_val.substring(decimal_pos);

    // add commas to left side of number
    left_side = formatNumber(left_side);

    // validate right side
    right_side = formatNumber(right_side);

    // On blur make sure 2 numbers after decimal
    if (blur === "blur") {
      right_side += "00";
    }

    // Limit decimal to only 2 digits
    right_side = right_side.substring(0, 2);

    // join number by .
    input_val = "$" + left_side + "." + right_side;

  } else {
    // no decimal entered
    // add commas to number
    // remove all non-digits
    input_val = formatNumber(input_val);
    input_val = "$" + input_val;

    // final formatting
    if (blur === "blur") {
      input_val += ".00";
    }
  }

  // send updated string to input
  input.val(input_val);

  // put caret back in the right position
  var updated_len = input_val.length;
  caret_pos = updated_len - original_len + caret_pos;
  input[0].setSelectionRange(caret_pos, caret_pos);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="currency-field" id="currency-field" pattern="^\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$" value="" data-type="currency" placeholder="$1,000,000.00" autocomplete ="off">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
// Jquery Dependency

$("input[data-type='currency']").on({
  keyup: function() {
    formatCurrency($(this));
  },
  blur: function() {
    var val = this.value.trim();
    val = val.substring(1);
    if (!isNaN(val) && +val <5) this.value=5;
    console.log(val)
    formatCurrency($(this), "blur");
  }
});


function formatNumber(n) {
  // format number 1000000 to 1,234,567
  return n.replace(/\D/g, "").replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
}


function formatCurrency(input, blur) {
  // appends $ to value, validates decimal side
  // and puts cursor back in right position.

  // get input value
  var input_val = input.val();

  // don't validate empty input
  if (input_val === "") {
    return;
  }

  // original length
  var original_len = input_val.length;

  // initial caret position 
  var caret_pos = input.prop("selectionStart");

  // check for decimal
  if (input_val.indexOf(".") >= 0) {

    // get position of first decimal
    // this prevents multiple decimals from
    // being entered
    var decimal_pos = input_val.indexOf(".");

    // split number by decimal point
    var left_side = input_val.substring(0, decimal_pos);
    var right_side = input_val.substring(decimal_pos);

    // add commas to left side of number
    left_side = formatNumber(left_side);

    // validate right side
    right_side = formatNumber(right_side);

    // On blur make sure 2 numbers after decimal
    if (blur === "blur") {
      right_side += "00";
    }

    // Limit decimal to only 2 digits
    right_side = right_side.substring(0, 2);

    // join number by .
    input_val = "$" + left_side + "." + right_side;

  } else {
    // no decimal entered
    // add commas to number
    // remove all non-digits
    input_val = formatNumber(input_val);
    input_val = "$" + input_val;

    // final formatting
    if (blur === "blur") {
      input_val += ".00";
    }
  }

  // send updated string to input
  input.val(input_val);

  // put caret back in the right position
  var updated_len = input_val.length;
  caret_pos = updated_len - original_len + caret_pos;
  input[0].setSelectionRange(caret_pos, caret_pos);
}
```

```css
.error { border: 3px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="currency-field" id="currency-field" pattern="^\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$" value="" data-type="currency" placeholder="$1,000,000.00" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: I just want to have a minimum value of $5 when a user enter a number below 5.

Comment: I got it. Thank You very much. @mplungjan